# Make any Notification Persistent

Tags: notifications

I am using the Google Calendar app for creating reminders for any event. The problem is that when I receive the notification for the event (usually a day before), I find that I am able to swipe the notification away. Is there a way to make this particular notification persistent until the event has ended?